# Why I can't write "é" in R console on ubuntu?

Tags: r

I have a code source write in `R`, when I tried to compare a variable with `"Numérique"` it doesn't work (I think this is an `utf8` encoding problem).

Like, when I type in the `R` console `"é"` it doesn't display (é). I don't know how to handle with it ?

For example, when I tried to test this condition with a variable fixed to `"Numérique"`, it does not work (it works for "Fixe" but not "Numérique")

```
if (variable_aff[Type%in% c("Fixe", "Numérique"), .N] > 0) 
{    
    saison <- match.arg(saison)
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your relevant source code, so that the community can replicate your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds more like a Linux setup question than a programming question. Check your console encoding settings.

Comment: Yes right, it was a Linux setup problem. Thank you @Robert